# .c files instead of .m in Objective-C projects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I noticed it some Objective-C projects some of the files that use a significant amount of C functions, store the code in `.c` files instead of `.m`. I know `.m` is for Objective-C and `.c` is for C but is there any benefit to using `.c` over `.m` when you can? Is there a performance increase or complication benefit? Would GCC or clang compile equivalent code differently in each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary benefit is that .c files can be used as-is in normal C programs and you know they won't accidentally incorporate Objective-C constructs that render them incompatible.

Comment: So would you expect much difference between the two compiles?

Comment: @Justin Meiners: No, I wouldn't. I have never noticed or heard of much difference between compiling as Objective-C or C99. AFAIK, the Objective-C compiler in both GCC and Clang compiles the plain C parts of an Objective-C program in the same way it would a plain C program. Note that the same is not true for Objective-C++ — the compiler for that is somewhat different and has longer compilation times than either Objective-C or C++ alone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Xcode will compile .c files with the 'C' compiler and the .m files with the 'Objective-C' compiler. It's the same compiler binary, just using different language options. That being the case, I wouldn't expect the relative performance to be too different.

Comment: So you wouldn't expect much difference between them?

Comment: I wouldn't expect much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Besides everything else, .c is good for cross platform development. The overhead of porting it from one platform to another is very low or almost negligible.  . And mostly the backend or the model of an application is developed using "C" where performance is required and you need a direct interaction with the machine. Such as interaction with hardware and stuff.

Comment: Im not asking about C code, im asking about not putting the C code in a .m file when most of the project is objective-c.